# Spring security 5.20 + SAML2

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-security-saml2

Is it possible to start a SAML2 authentication process restricting to certain URLs? So my idea is to use a URL like /saml2login that launches all the SAML authentication process.

I've tr¡ed with something similar to:

```
  httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/saml2login").authenticated()
                .and()
                .saml2Login()
                .relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(
                        new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(
                                getSaml2AuthenticationConfiguration()
                        )
                );
```

But It doesn't work

Comment: You can definitely apply SAML2 authentication to a subset of URLs. Can you explain how your configuration isn't working? Is SAML2 not being triggered?